# Migration error when adding a column to an existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to add a users username to a `song`.

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs 
  ...
end
```

**app/models/song.rb**

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

I'm trying to make a migration to add a username table to my songs table

```
class AddUsernameToSongs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :songs, :username, :string
  end
end
```

But I keep getting an uninitialized constant error when I try to run rake db:migrate

I want to be able to on each song call

```
<%= song.username %>
```

To post the author of the track.

I'm using devise to set up my users and the devise table already has a username field.

Comment: Post your full migration error and the filename of your migration. Lastly, `song.username` isn't magic. You need to be sure you assign a value to that attribute.

Comment: Your belongs_to :user line in song.rb is going to assume you have a user_id column on the songs table.  Do you have this foreign key column?

Comment: Don't add a username column to your song table. If you have the relation setup correctly, you should be able to access the username by doing `song.user.username`

Answer (score 1):

Its a better idea to link to the song to a user by id than just the username.

*if you don't already have this. I think that you do as you say you have an association.*

```
class AddUserToSongs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :songs, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

In your song model you can add a method called ** author **

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
  def author
    user.name # this can be username or what ever field in the user's table you want 
  end
end
```

Now in your views you can do something like this.

```
- songs.each do |song|
  = song.author
  %br
```

I hope that this helps. 
Happy Hacking